# BeforeAll and AfterAll hooks in a separate gem

Tags: ruby, rspec

**Background**:
We have a monorepo of services, and each service has unit tests and runs their own tests using rspec, for example:

```
repo/appA/spec/*_spec.rb
repo/appB/spec/*_spec.rb
repo/appC/subserviceD/spec/*_spec.rb
repo/appC/subserviceE/spec/*_spec.rb
```

**My goal**:
To preface, I'm new to the Ruby ecosystem, but I would like to setup a separate gem (an isolated repo from the monorepo) which is responsible for running some code after specs finish, basically an rspec afterall hook, or any time after the tests are done.

For anyone familiar with the Python/pytest ecosystem, this is basically analogous to writing a "pytest plugin," where you can add extra functionality to existing hooks.

**Question**:

- Is it possible to create an `afterall` RSpec hook (or something behaviour) in a separate gem, and any code that imports this gem automatically has the hook applied after their tests run?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a singular spec helper file? If so, you could call the gem's method from there

Comment: @maxpleaner When looking at the [rspec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec),  it looks like spec helpers go in the `spec/helper` folders with an import `require "spec_helper"`. 

Does that mean we could write a helper spec in our gem with the appropriate hooks implemented, and just import it with something like `require mygem/helper`?

Comment: its worth a try